# How to achieve this "Neo Noir" kind effect with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects, plugin, technique

I'm a big fan of John Lumio's work, a great photographer. I noticed that all his images has a special filter / edition. I would like to know if someone has some clue of how to achieve this effect.

Thank you all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A great deal of this is done in the camera, not via post processing.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried and why you are not content with the results?

Answer (score 1):

There is very little filtering, if anything perhaps little adjustments to the colour balance, and shadows and highlights, in post.  Most of what you see is down to camera techniques.

To get a similar effect, shoot a street scene at night, using a tripod, a fast prime lens with aperture open fully, shoot in RAW, use the histogram in the camera to expose to the left (very slight under exposure) to avoid clipping the highlights.

Then open in Photoshop, and in Adobe Camera RAW, adjust the white balance as necessary, recover the highlights, and boost the shadows (fill), slightly increase the exposure, add some clarity, add a bit of vignetting, and you may also need to apply some noise reduction.

Back in PS, perhaps add a curves adjustment layer, select the blue channel and very slightly lift the curve to make the shadows ever so slightly bluish.